# ffmpeg convert directory GIF in linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, gif, mp4

Hi i'm trying to convert a directory of gifs to mp4 but i don't know how to i'm use this code for single file please help me
`!ffmpeg -i /content/drive/MyDrive/1/ -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" /content/drive/MyDrive/2/${f%.gif}.mp4`

Converting gif directory to mp4

Answer (score 1):

The following example should do what you want.

```
for f in /path/to/gifs/*.gif; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" "/path/to/mp4s/${f%.gif}.mp4"; done
```